# System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current (and HttpContext.Current.User) has different claims with the exact same request depending on caller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

This is something I have never seen before. When executing an identical request to ASP.NET Web API 2 from two different applications I get a different response. I narrowed it down to `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` being the culprit.

```
var principal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;

if (principal == null) return false;

if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return false;
```

According to MSDN `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` just calls `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` by default but I still do not understand how this can happen.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I then tried to use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` instead but this gives the same result.

How can two identical HTTP Requests from the same machine generate different response in this case? The requests can be sent over and over again with the same result. I can even stop the application and IIS Express, start it again and the result is the same. What is happening here? It must be some sort of session that is stored on the server but I don't get why the values differ with an ***identical requests***. **There is nothing misspelled in the request itself, I can copy the request generated by Postman and it works with BURP, if it is sent via Postman it fails**. I don't think it is Postman specific either. I used the command `Copy as PowerShell` from `Chrome Developer Tools` -> `Network tab` from a working request and I got the same result with `Invoke-WebRequest`.

IIS uses `Anonymous Authentication`. The application uses `IAppBuilder - app.UseCookieAuthentication` with `AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie` and a custom `CookieName`.

With Burp the request gives `principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true`

[image]

[image]

[image]

With Postman the exact same request gives `principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false`. Postman Gui does a line break on `-` but the copied value works in Burp so nothing wrong there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Postman cookie value in UTF-8:

```
XXX=_1gQcJZ_zwNNS6f5OO0mD5y4pPHATpzw7uRHQZnZidNfYYec9S3MkR-d9aaxx1AilQSCK_h1-9LVS1uVM_JLJDTty5Nilsx4njjOCsrefgBOvnkt9CIzt_fGu0kzgsi_VbrCSO-txXtLhrOBT61bFskQd0i2yF_xrnqdOoW6yzKmUPrdomxiABMsC-NYw5aSGD9d81ht-oreUGqJKoDQ7EJ0BzUc-Y6BDqrJv5TrIfdgwgOsk2cFN9gfrlN9DQQQpRAAEv5mgiXDmMpUpNvsP-k-CFu69sl1ZlTXOLR5ECSrq7woeIhea6-L9g1mwpslqAV_saLtv0DcbR525gR0tSrpEIuHLwj_TSqTQ1IPHqfcqSP-RzP2jGoz85y6W2glFkfFxAXJBMTjoz4U1fvjURL5qMEuC2IpQZqKGoSbp8xICFA01yY1zzHKxXnKL8MIqDNAe9urQn2W-gmwje9bzFAkft3eYYjctrCrGMRocgQ; __RequestVerificationToken=HOA5v8aiHqUhzZP3fkKMUyi336D7JydqWMSWI-VThQgMrVRZEllKglaGaLOUP0z49ZEuJsrEaYbrLaLCxMgAwxJtfSJhGvsRaB6e3tlMPjc1
```

BURP cookie value in UTF-8:

```
XXX=_1gQcJZ_zwNNS6f5OO0mD5y4pPHATpzw7uRHQZnZidNfYYec9S3MkR-d9aaxx1AilQSCK_h1-9LVS1uVM_JLJDTty5Nilsx4njjOCsrefgBOvnkt9CIzt_fGu0kzgsi_VbrCSO-txXtLhrOBT61bFskQd0i2yF_xrnqdOoW6yzKmUPrdomxiABMsC-NYw5aSGD9d81ht-oreUGqJKoDQ7EJ0BzUc-Y6BDqrJv5TrIfdgwgOsk2cFN9gfrlN9DQQQpRAAEv5mgiXDmMpUpNvsP-k-CFu69sl1ZlTXOLR5ECSrq7woeIhea6-L9g1mwpslqAV_saLtv0DcbR525gR0tSrpEIuHLwj_TSqTQ1IPHqfcqSP-RzP2jGoz85y6W2glFkfFxAXJBMTjoz4U1fvjURL5qMEuC2IpQZqKGoSbp8xICFA01yY1zzHKxXnKL8MIqDNAe9urQn2W-gmwje9bzFAkft3eYYjctrCrGMRocgQ; __RequestVerificationToken=HOA5v8aiHqUhzZP3fkKMUyi336D7JydqWMSWI-VThQgMrVRZEllKglaGaLOUP0z49ZEuJsrEaYbrLaLCxMgAwxJtfSJhGvsRaB6e3tlMPjc1
```

**Update 2:**

From the command `Copy as PowerShell` from `Chrome Developer Tools ->  Network tab`.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost:44349/api/crud/customer" -Headers @{"path"="/api/crud/custo
mer"; "pragma"="no-cache"; "cookie"="__RequestVerificationToken=3gvrynl8SRhi5CBG-umg5eGii3yUOrHJAQQ7jMXhN_hOk0EGS2XdIDIS
afhbBZuS3JCCJdP6V60K_crzcQF71aw2totf9CUTPheHBmTNBRM1; io=iki1JghnuzWahlUBAAAJ; XXX=SUdlUpzYNbXJbhPxj4KY6-GC31hHyyPN_IZ88
zsXHXIpqzro6t_C5-m8BC_s2xev5SINoI-0316o7ITb6dsRA5b5oYJX2MXIWD2iaMWGADqAZeLDLoeQPHo6B6a8dQ-j2YkI17I4cjQ7SQKBiUCwN3DIZckY8
HHnWqF6LGVr79nWG3R1pqI62S3UKgEXOjhFTpEA3fD3clPti4ShG88PWnxa5ypGGDjUolcqjkusylpLAWZ3Jc8K4y-K_WnA-3EX_nNyCHp3Tk8omXHq1LgvQ
J3EsqdNvELL2KcwvUCn3ni7ktSt0Vzl6G7vL3AfZhDQb41bn90l4haR9UGvLOqSkZ_cu5IiHzvsFrps6QJ3HJ8d-Dcb4A2soVjnozh7SsZxnz-HppwhV2UaW
ANvi6MsD4kwvBreJrO9nLMOBRBXhzEInoL0baqkn_nhEtxqAndZHiHcbuoPfz8xGmgV-ilTxZRAnJ8ZAwD3yHREgJsodVg"; "accept-encoding"="gzip
, deflate, br"; "accept-language"="en-US,en;q=0.9,sv-SE;q=0.8,sv;q=0.7"; "user-agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win
64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36"; "accept"="*/*"; "cache-control"="no
-cache"; "authority"="localhost:44349"; "referer"="https://localhost:44349/"; "scheme"="https"; "xsrf-token"="_GHoZagVRo
FBIAyoMmT7UEZk44wfKsGlscub-bvoeRMTpysPS_d2uccvyyvPdWDf7srVfmNqM4JN1firyN-Q35UN5DCMew0eq6OV9M_4--i_klYEJcXYSodFi_wAymDVlQ
CPLroCvDNkwuhdoZvyug2"; "method"="GET"}
```

Comment: Yeah so the problem is the cookie value, given that's the only thing that results in being authenticated or not. Check the cookies' values from both requests and compare them. Given PostMan uses Chrome, perhaps you have a cookie in Chrome that's persisted a bit too hard. Try clearing the site data in Chrome.

Comment: @CodeCaster Believe me I have tried. I have copied the non working value from `Postman` to `BURP` and it works there. Updated the question with the values used so you can check yourself. They use encoding UTF-8.

Comment: I'm not asking about the values you _think_ Postman sends. I'm asking to inspect the cookie headers at the ASP.NET side. See what the server receives. What you enter in Postman is not always what it sends.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you so much. Sometimes you feel really stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huge thanks to @CodeCaster. Sometimes you feel like a n00b all over. Looked at `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies` and indeed these were empty. Hovered over the Cookie header in `Postman` and then I saw the value `Restricted Header (use Postman Interceptor)`. What really got me here was that `Invoke-WebRequest` in `Powershell` got the same error code.

[image]

Upgraded to the Postman native app instead of using the Chrome Application and then everything worked.

[image]